# How to pause taskscheduleR at night

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks

I have a R program to execute every 2 hours at day time, say between 8:30-18:30. It seems like everything works except there is no option to pause from 18:30 to 8:30 next morning. Please help! Thanks. The code I used to successfully execute every 2 hours is as follows.

```
 library(taskscheduleR)
 taskscheduler_create(taskname = "code_hr", rscript = 
 "C:/Users/me/Documents/code.R",schedule = "HOURLY", starttime = "08:30", 
 modifier = 2, startdate = format(as.Date("2017-08-14"), "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Comment: Which argument in taskscheduleR should be modified for pause purpose? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there were some arguments I didn't know. @Hack-R. I have checked task scheduler but never used it before. Do you mind pointing out where I should edit? This is a last minute change to the program to be executed soon. I don't want to mess it up. Many thanks!

Comment: I've moved my answer from comments to an official answer below. Please let me know if you have any questions/trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `taskscheduleR` often requires a little editing in Windows Task Scheduler to add more advanced options such as this.

As the first step I typically create the task as best I can with `taskscheduleR`, like you did. This helps you to get several R-related settings correct.

For the 2nd step do the following:

1. Click Start
2. Search for "schedule tasks" and click the corresponding icon to open the Task Scheduler
3. Click Library
4. Find and open (edit) your task
5. Click Triggers
6. Click edit
7. Make sure the task is set to run daily
8. Look at the Advanced options (below) and set it to run every 2 hours with a duration of 10 hours (beginning at 08:30)

There's a nice screenshot on a related Super User thread: https://superuser.com/questions/345319/how-to-schedule-a-windows-task-to-repeat-every-day-within-a-time-range

Answer (score 1):

If your solutions is to use the duration argument, just pass it on when using taskscheduler_create

as in

```
library(taskscheduleR)
 taskscheduler_create(taskname = "code_hr", rscript = 
 "C:/Users/me/Documents/code.R",schedule = "HOURLY", starttime = "08:30", 
 modifier = 2, startdate = format(as.Date("2017-08-14"), "%m/%d/%Y"), schtasks_extra = "/DU 10")

library(taskscheduleR)
 taskscheduler_create(taskname = "code_hr", rscript = 
 "C:/Users/me/Documents/code.R",schedule = "HOURLY", starttime = "08:30", 
 modifier = 2, startdate = format(as.Date("2017-08-14"), "%m/%d/%Y"), schtasks_extra = "/DU 18:20")
```

Comment: Thank you @jwijffels. This would be great if it works. So schtasks_extra = "/DU 10" or schtasks_extra = "/DU 18:20"(I suppose you meant 18:30) sets the duration for 10 hours for that day and then resume at 8:30 in the following morning? Just realize you are the author of the package. Really appreciate your response!

Comment: The best way to find out is trying it out.

Comment: It doesn't work for me @jwijffels. "/DU 18:30" doesn't execute and "/DU 10" returns an error: [1] "ERROR: Invalid value specified for /DU. Valid range: 0000:02 to 9999:59."
[2] "Type \"SCHTASKS /CREATE /?\" for usage."                                 
attr(,"status")
[1] 1

Comment: /DU 10:15 works for me, maybe you need to delete your task again. For more information on what can be passed on to schtasks_extra, see https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR/blob/master/inst/docs/schtasks.pdf